# Where to put "Favorite" and "Buy" buttons in a shopping list app?

Tags: buttons, lists

I'm creating a perfume shopping application and i want to know where is the right place to put "add to cart" and "toggle favorite" button.
i placed them in both perfume list and detailed page of a perfume that comes when someone touch that item in the list.
what's the best user friendly way to put these buttons?

here is a sample prototype:

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is logical.

As per my opinion you have already solved this problem (I mean, you already have the better solution). The reason is if any user is a frequent purchaser then from the complete list he will just add it to cart. So placing add to cart on the list of perfumes is perfectly fine.

If I am a new user, I would prefer reading some description and then add it to cart or mark it as favorite.Hence placing both the icons in the details page is also fine.

Remember we have to **give shortcuts to frequent users** as stated by Shneiderman here : faculty.washington.edu/jtenenbg/courses/360/f04/sessions/schneidermanGoldenRules.html

Answer (score 0):

On the above screens, the button is not prominent on the touch screen.

Consider making the Buy or Add to Cart button and any other calls to action prominent as well as making the shopping cart **visible and accessible wherever users are on a mobile** try to create new section below the product and put both button.

It should be easy for your users to checkout from anywhere as well as inform customers where they are in the checkout process and provide a clear confirmation that a customer has successfully completed an order. It’s really the valid stuff to improve shopping on the mobile Web.

check [this link from Google](http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs) on some good UX principles: